# Functional equation $\int_z^{2z} [f(x)-f(z)] dx = 0$

Tags: differential-equations, functional-equations

Suppose a continuous function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following equation for all $z \in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$,
$$\int_z^{2z} [f(x)-f(z)] dx = 0.$$
It is clear that a constant function $f(x)=c$ satisfies it. I would like to prove that there are no other such continous functions.

Note: this is a missing part of a larger proof I'm working on. I've already verified that if $f$ is a polynomial then it must be constant. Any hints on how to prove it for arbitrary continuous functions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to truncate your domain of integration to $[z,2z] \cap [a,b]$?

Comment: Good point, thanks! I updated the question slightly.

Comment: With the update, the statement is no longer true: If $a<b<2a$ then the condition is vacuously true, but $f$ needn't be constant. And I suspect it is also false if $[a,b] \cap [2a,2b]$ is small but nonempty. The most natural formulation of the problem seems to be for functions on $[0, \infty)$, but is this what is relevant to your application?

Comment: Again, good points! In my application $a=0$ and $0<b<\infty$. But it would be enough to have it for $[0,1]$ interval. I'll update the text once more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p$ be a zero of $2^{p+1}-p-2$ other than $-1$ and $0$ (e.g. one is approximately $2.54536493037426+10.7539751752688 i$).  Then
the real and imaginary parts of $f(x) = x^p$ satisfy the equation.
Note that (with $f(0)=0$) $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ if $\text{Re}(p) > 0$.

Comment: "... $p$ be a zero of $2^{p+1} - p - 2$ ...": should there be an $x$ somewhere?

Comment: No, there shouldn't.  I mean a solution of the equation $2^{p+1} - p - 2 = 0$.

Comment: This is more complex than I expected. Do you mean $f(x) = Re(x^p)$? Any hints on how to prove this? In my application, I also have that $f(x)<0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer! But it seems that the value $f(x)$ fluctuates around $0$, which means that when I impose an additional constraint (that I should have mentioned) that $f(x)<0$, it does not work. Any hints how to approach this would be helpful.

Comment: Since the equation is linear in $f$, a linear combination of solutions is a solution.  So take $f(x) = -1 +  \text{Re}(x^p)$, which will be negative for $0 < x < 1$.

Comment: Thanks again! It is a good answer to my question. Unfortunately, it still does not help me in my problem, since what $f(x)$ from here is actually a derivative of some real-valued continuously differentiable function $F(X)$. Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: $\text{Re}(x^p)$ is the derivative of $\text{Re}(x^{p+1}/(p+1))$.